# When running TextTransform.exe, how to distinguish between TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor and TextTemplatingFileGenerator?

Tags: msbuild, t4, css

When running TextTransform.exe, how to distinguish between TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor and TextTemplatingFileGenerator?
I cannot use msbuild as most people refer to, so I'm looking for specific thing: how to run TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor in command line for a given TT file.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

TextTransform.exe doesn't support preprocessing unfortunately.  If you can't use the msbuild tasks (remember you can use msbuild standalone to just do this step inside some other process), then you could write a custom host.  There's a sample on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126519.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I created a custom host and this works fine, but this will cause TextTemplating to build an assembly _runtime_ for each of my TT file (embedded as resources). The "preprocessor" approach I liked better, because it gave me final class built together with the code.